# Grails - Disable default url mappings

Tags: grails

I want to disable default url mappings of grails. I removed all mappings from UrlMappings.groovy file. It is completely empty. But when I run url-mappings-report command, I still see default mappings as

```
Dynamic Mappings
 |    *     | ERROR: 404                                        | View:   /notFound        |
 |    *     | ERROR: 500                                        | View:   /error           |
 |    *     | /                                                 | View:   /index           |
 |    *     | /${controller}/${action}?/${id}?(.${format)?      | Action: (default action) |
```

After deleting all mappings in UrlMappings.groovy file, I expect to get 404 not found or an error but It works because of the last mapping we see. How can I get rid of these default mappings ?

Comment: Have you considered adding that mapping to your URLMappings.groovy and pointing it to a controller that you use to return 404?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore That doesn't get rid of the mappings, which is I think what the asker wants... "How can I get rid of these default mappings ?"

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Good point. I guess I got a bit confused by "want to disable default url mappings" and "expect to get 404". You are right. They want to remove them entirely. :D

Comment: "They want to remove them entirely." - Right.  Unclear why you would want that, but it does sound like that is what he wants.

Comment: Actually I want my own mappings. But even when I have my own mappings these defaults are still there and breaking my other mappings. That is why I want to get rid of them. Ofcourse I will have another mappings after that. Just did not mention about it to keep question simple. And as I said 404 or an error, just I expect it to don't work. But It does. That is what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your project it is difficult to say where that mapping is coming from.  It is possible you are using a plugin that provides that mapping.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/alituranurls.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/alituranurls/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/alituranurls/UrlMappings.groovy contains nothing but the 404 mapping:

```
package alituranurls

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

The URL mapping report is consistent with that:

```
$ ./grailsw url-mappings-report
 |    *     | ERROR: 404      | View:   /notFound        |
```

Comment: We thought about that yesterday but didn't have time to try it. There are a lot of package which are generated from application forge I will check them today. Thnx for your time and answer. Cheers!

Comment: I found one of my plugins have the url mapping. Thnx for the answer again.